# saving .ipynb files as .py file in jupyer notebook removes backslashes in code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I downloaded my .ipynb file as from jupyter notebook as .py file, some of my python syntax are slightly changed in the .py file, specifically that the backslashes are removed. For example:

.ipynb file:

```
    return f"lineone" +\
f"linetwo"
```

.py file:

```
return f"lineone" +    f"linetwo"
```

Is this intentional or is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this behaviour is because a backslash is traditionally an escape character in text files i.e. it escapes the character immediately following it.

If you want to preserve the backslash in your `.py` files just add another backslash i.e.

```python
    return f"lineone" +\\
f"linetwo"
```

That should ensure a backslash is written to the exported `.py` file.